# How can I apply ellipsis to the text parameter in android compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am developing an Android app using the Android Jetpack Compose.

The app supports so many languages.
So there are cases where the word order is different.

Here are same text per language:

1. English: The Greatest Marvel Hero is 'Doctor Strange'
2. Korean: 가장 강한 Marvel Hero는 'Doctor Strange'입니다
3. Japanese: 最も偉大なマーベルヒーローは「Doctor Strange」です

The 'Doctor Strange' is the parameter, so it should be changed dynamically.
So I define the string resource like:

```xml
<string name="bundle_title_suffix" translatable="false">The Greatest Marvel Hero is \'%1$s\'</string>
<string name="bundle_title_prefix" translatable="false">\'%1$s\' is very powerful Marvel Hero.</string>
<string name="bundle_title_middle" translatable="false">Sorcerer \'%1$s\' is very powerful.</string>
```

And my compose code is:

```kotlin
@Composable
private fun Title(baseText: Int) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .border(0.5.dp, Gray200)
            .padding(8.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        buildAnnotatedString {

        }
        Text(
            text = stringResource(id = baseText, "Doctor..."),
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1F, fill = false),
            fontSize = 20.sp,
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
            maxLines = 1
        )

        HorizontalSpacer(size = 16.dp)

        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Default.KeyboardArrowRight,
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier.size(36.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

And the result is:

[image]

But I want to keep the full text, and I want to ellipsis only the parameter text.
So what I want to is below:

[image]

The difference is "What is ellipsis".

How can I do this?